# raise ArgumentError ruby

Tags: ruby, error-handling

I have a simple Die roll class.  How to I test for an  ArgumentError?

```
 class Die
   def initialize(num)
    if num < 1
      raise(ArgumentError)
    end
    @num = num
  end
  def sides
    return @sides
  end

  def roll
    @value = rand(@num) + 1
    return @value
  end
end
```

Here's my failed attempt.

```
assert_raise ArgumentError do
  zero = 0
  die = Die.new(zero)
  puts die.sides == raise(ArgumentError)
end
```

Comment: You don't need to use those `return` keywords explicitly.. it is implicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This implementation should help you assert whether an error was raised or not:

```
class TestDie < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase 
  def test_argument_error
    assert_raises ArgumentError do
      Die.new(0)
    end
  end

  def test_argument_error_not_raised
    refute_raises ArgumentError do
      Die.new(2)
    end
  end
end
```

For refuting that an exception should not be raised you can write your own refute_raises method similar to this:

```
def refute_raises
  yield
rescue Exception => err
  flunk "Expected no failures but #{mu_pp(err).chomp} was raised."
end
```

Documentation for [assert_raises](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/MiniTest/Assertions/assert_raises) and [flunk](http://apidock.com/ruby/MiniTest/Assertions/flunk)

Comment: Good for adding the both side test cases, but you could notify me also to improve mine..

Answer (score 2):

Do as below :

```
class TestDie < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase 
  def test_argument_error
    assert_raises(ArgumentError) { Die.new(0) }
  end
end
```

Here is the documentation of [`assert_raises`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_raises)

> Fails unless the block raises one of exp. Returns the exception matched so you can check the message, attributes, etc.